# drain hose for chest freezer

Tags: drain, drainage, freezer

I'm trying to build a DIY ice bath (Wim Hof style ice baths) using a chest freezer.

I have a Magic Chef small size chest freezer (pic below). I need to drain the water in it every couple of months or so. There's a drain hole inside the freezer with a plug. And there's a small drain outlet to the side. The outside drain hole is smooth on the inside, and has no threading. I thought it was 1/2" wide and got a 1/2" pipe joint from the hardware store. However, the joint is too large for the hole. My question is:

1. How to I go about sizing it (I tried using a measuring tape last time but apparently that didn't work. Anyone got an easy hack to do this?)
2. Is there a name for the kind of joint I should be looking for?

---

The drainage outlet is to the bottom-left of the freezer in the pic below.

[image]

---

I've put my index finger tip near the hole to help understand its size better.

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use the freezer to make ice? ... put ice in the bathtub

Comment: @jsotola Good point. I don't have a bathtub unfortunately.

Comment: I think you will find the capacity of your freezer to make ice is low; Or, not worth the  the effort to build a circulation system.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Thanks. I want to fill water to about half the capacity, and run the water at around 40 degrees Celsius. There are some videos on YouTube of people who've done this before. I'm going to give it a try, and if it doesn't work, I'll try something else.

Comment: Wait, what??? 40°C doesn't sound _anything_ like an **ice** bath to me! That sounds more like a day roasting on the beach!

Comment: 40F, presumably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A siphon might be better if it is a lot of water.

1:  **No hose will fit in.**  That drain hole has a flat side.  I wondered what sort of plug thing would go it.  The answer looks like "none".  The instruction manual https://c.searspartsdirect.com/mmh/lis_pdf/OWNM/L0702364.pdf
says that water should just drip out into a pan.  Another source recommended a bunch of towels.

2:  You will need to reach through all the water to unplug the drain.  Doable but not fun.  I hope you have long, orangutan like arms for this endeavor, and in general.

3. **Siphon.**  I think you might be better off siphoning the bulk of the water out.  You can siphon it out with a garden hose to the drain.  You won't have to get wet or use all your towels.  I change the water in my aquarium this way.  If you want every last bit you can get that with the drain hole and the pan.
4. **Are walls strong enough for this use?**  I worry that if this freezer is really full of water and ice it will produce a lot of lateral pressure on the walls.  I do not think the walls of a freezer are made to withstand that kind of pressure.  Make sure the environment of this freezer will be safe if a wall comes loose while you are out of town.

Comment: Thank you for digging out the instruction manual. You are the MVP.